# WPF C# webbrowser all sounds disable

Tags: c#, wpf, browser

Can I disable/remove/turn off all sounds In my app - webbrowser.

(1) Is it possible to do in XAML?

(2) How i can do it in C# - code behind?

my browser:

Xaml:

```
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.Integration;assembly=WindowsFormsIntegration"


<my:WindowsFormsHost Name="windowsFormsHost"/>
```

Code behind:

```
System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser Browser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
            windowsFormsHost.Child = Browser;
```

Comment: which system are you targeting? WinPhone, > Vista or <= XP?

Comment: Two points:
1. Its not very useful to rage on comments via editing the question - therefore comments are there.
2. To get whether it is possible in xaml, please tell your used webbrowser control
3. In C# it depends on the target system

Comment: 1. Taken care of by reviewers. 2. – 3. – 4. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278186/how-do-i-disable-the-wpf-webbrowser-controls-click-noise

Comment: 4. not a duplicate, since this only handles click sounds. He wants to disable all output - from online radio to youtube

Comment: Since this question is marked as a duplicate, I can't supply any answer, but for the WebBrowser control itself it is impossible to disable all audio. If you're using XP or lower, the only way is to disable the system master volume. On Vista or higher, you can disable sound for certain applications, so it is possible to do so there in C#. Just search a bit about Windows7 sound control in C#.